# compiling gcc with -O3 technically increases my cache miss rate

Tags: c, gcc, caching

I've been profiling a bit with cachegrind and noticed something. When i compile with -O3 i had fewer data fetches but the same amount of cache misses resulting in a higher miss rate. This is great but it just seems like a funny weird thing to me and i'd like to know what's going on behind the scene. The only other relevant compiler option i have turned on is -march=native . For comparison,

Without O3

```
==16951== D   refs:        923,170,681  (817,941,424 rd   + 105,229,257 wr)
==16951== D1  misses:        9,477,102  (  8,115,150 rd   +   1,361,952 wr)
==16951== LLd misses:          647,219  (    262,227 rd   +     384,992 wr)
==16951== D1  miss rate:           1.0% (        1.0%     +         1.3%  )
==16951== LLd miss rate:           0.1% (        0.0%     +         0.4%  )
```

With O3

```
==16978== D   refs:      218,804,125  (205,979,405 rd   + 12,824,720 wr)
==16978== D1  misses:      9,372,533  (  8,016,083 rd   +  1,356,450 wr)
==16978== LLd misses:        647,195  (    262,191 rd   +    385,004 wr)
==16978== D1  miss rate:         4.3% (        3.9%     +       10.6%  )
==16978== LLd miss rate:         0.3% (        0.1%     +        3.0%  )
```

Comment: Some number of misses are unavoidable: They’re called “cold” misses because the data just wasn’t in the cache to begin with. Your cache could be gigantic and perfect in every way but if the data isn’t already in cache it misses and must be loaded. That could be a reasonable explanation for what you’re seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I know ill never have a perfect cache. Moreso the question is : How did O3 reduce the number of references to a quarter, while having the same number of cache misses.

Comment: I am merely guessing, since you show no code, but -O3 may have activated some optimization that reduces the number of references (e.g. 4-way vectorization with SSE, or loop fusion).

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to vectorization:

```
-O3

Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2
and also turns on ... -ftree-vectorize and -fipa-cp-clone options.
```

(from GCC manpage).